# Passing pointer to pointer and reallocate space

Tags: c, pointers, memory, realloc

I post this sample code in order to explain my problem. I'm trying to passing among functions a pointer to integer. If you compile & run this code you'll see that strange numbers appears and I can't get why. I think it's a bad use of `realloc()`. If anybody could give a hint or maybe redirect me to some questions similar to this I'll appreciate. I search for this problem but I can't find anything similar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void myFunction(int **output);


int main(){

    int *indices;
    myFunction(&indices);

    printf("{");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){//suppose also for some mysterious reasons that I know min_size in the main
        printf("%i,", indices[i]);
    }
    printf("}\n");

    return 0;
}


void myFunction(int **output){

    int size = 130;//allocating big amount of space
    int* indices = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);

    //...start doing mysterious stuffs....
    int min_size = 10; 
    for(int i=0;i<min_size;i++){
        indices[i] = i;//just for saving something
    }
    //...end doing mysterious stuffs...

    //now for some reasons I know I need only min_size elements and all other are wasting space so I reallocate
    indices = realloc(indices,min_size);//resizing in order to save space

    *output = indices;
}
```

Comment: Don't reassign back to the pointer you pass to `realloc`, think about if `realloc` fails and return `NULL` then you will lose the original pointer and have a memory leak.

Comment: As for your problem, `realloc` just like `malloc` takes its size ***in bytes***. Ten bytes is very different from ten `int` elements.

Comment: You're allocating `malloc sizeof(int)*size` but reallocating: `realloc(indices, min_size`. I think it should be `realloc(indices, min_size*sizeof(int))`

Comment: Can't believe it is that simple! Thank you! It works! I completely misunderstood the realloc signature. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using realloc incorrectly. The size of the reallocated extent must be

```
min_size * sizeof( int )
```

Here you are

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void myFunction(int **output);


int main( void )
{

    int *indices;
    myFunction(&indices);

    printf("{");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){//suppose also for some mysterious reasons that I know min_size in the main
        printf("%i,", indices[i]);
    }
    printf("}\n");

    return 0;
}


void myFunction(int **output){

    int size = 130;//allocating big amount of space
    int* indices = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);

    *output = indices;
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    //...start doing mysterious stuffs....
    int min_size = 10; 
    for(int i=0;i<min_size;i++){
        indices[i] = i;//just for saving something
    }
    //...end doing mysterious stuffs...

    //now for some reasons I know I need only min_size elements and all other are wasting space so I reallocate

    indices = realloc(indices, min_size * sizeof( int ) );//resizing in order to save space
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    if ( indices ) *output = indices;
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

The program output is

```
{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,}
```